# android app button thats save the predefined contact to address book

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I need to add contact button in app, if user clicks on that a contact is stored in the user address book, with or without prompt.

```
Name:- sharukh khan

website:- www.google.com

Phone:- 9999999999

Phone:- 8888888888

email:- s@p.com

skype:-

linkedin:-

etc
```

can anyone help?
thanks naina

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using Intents, you create an intent of type ContactsContract and you add the contact info as Extras.

Follow [This Guide](https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/modify-data.html) for details at the part:  **"Create an Intent"**

You can add the prompt using a Dialog Box later